# How to do average of gauge metric in Prometheus

Tags: group-by, prometheus, gauge, prometheus-alertmanager

I have gauge metric (sample below). And I want to find the average of metric of last 10 hours for each hour. Not combine of 10 hours. I can easily do in SQl by hour in group by clause. But do not have good idea in prometheus query

```
{group="PrometheusDemo",resource="FinanceServicesGo",service="analyticsA",warning="1000"} 6
{group="PrometheusDemo",resource="FinanceServicesGo",service="analyticsB",warning="3000"} 9
{group="PrometheusDemo",resource="FinanceServicesGo",service="analyticsC",warning="2000"} 8
...
....
...
```

I tried below query -

```
avg({__name__="metricA"}) by (group, service)
```

Edited question 
**Problem statement**

I have a metric A, with time and value (see image below). In **hourly avg** column, I took the average of each hours. and then in **avg over avg** column I took the avg of previous averaged column. I got value **9.12** but If I take the combine average of last 2 hour I will get **8.1**. I want avg over avg value (9.12) using prometheus query. How I can do this by using prometheus query?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for subqueries:

- https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/
- https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#subquery

`avg_over_time(avg by (group, service) (avg_over_time({__name__="metricA"}[1h]))[10h:1h])`

The outermost query `avg_over_time(query[10h:1h])` will evaluate a time period for `10h` back, execute the `query` at `1h` interval and then average those 10 results for each time series.

The inner query `avg by (group, service) (avg_over_time({__name__="metricA"}[1h]))` will run 10 times. `avg_over_time({__name__="metricA"}[1h])` query will average each initial time series over `1h` then get averaged by group and service by `avg by (group, service) ()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following query will do the job:

```
avg by (group, service) (avg_over_time({__name__="metricA"}[1h]))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I want avg of each hour from last 10hour. Does it gives the same? if I update the query with 10h, then it will give avg of last 10hours datapoint. But how to get avg of each hour not whole 10hours means 10 output from query.

Comment: This will give the average for the last hour continuously, for all your data in the past and in the future, when more data arrive.

Comment: I think answer from @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira is right. I suspect you're painting this in Grafana and over there, you need to specify a Min Interval as 1h in the Query editor and you'll get an 1h avg at each hour of your time range. If your range is last 10h, you'll get 10 points on the chart. Makes sense?

Comment: @sskrlj I am using this query somewhere else. I need avg of each hour means 10 results for past 10 hours

Comment: @lucy, you'll need to elaborate on somewhere else part.

Comment: @sskrlj I want to use this result to again get avg over this values. Meant avg over avg. I have updated the question with one example. Please have a look.